# Eager loading in SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to use Eager loading in my application.

```
db.Shop.findAll({where:{id:shopId},{ include: [ db.ShopTranslation ] })
.then(function(s) {
    res.jsonp(s);
});
```

I wrote the code above but it does not include ShopTranslation. I am sure my models are right.

Comment: sequelize version? Also I think you don't need object wrapper for include.